# iPhone 5S camera focus

Tags: camera, iphone

Does anyone else often get blurry images when taking photos with iPhone 5S? I just feel they are more frequent than on my iPhone 4 and was wondering if anyone else experienced the same.

Comment: nope - i think the 5S Camera is a lot better ... but Focus is Softwarebased

Answer (score 2):

Blurry photos occur because:

- skin oil or other cruft (pocket lint) is on the lens
- the camera software is focusing on distant objects (when you want a closeup,) or focusing on close objects (when you want a distant object.)

If you are having trouble focusing, tap in the yellow focus box on the screen. You will notice that the software shows a larger yellow box when it detects a closeup shot, and a smaller box when it detects a distance shot.

Answer (score 0):

just tap on the object you want to focus on before taking the picture. if it's still blurry take camera further from object.